# How to load javascript libraries after content is loaded in Angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, angular, libraries

At this moment my javascript libraries are linked with a script tag within the head of my index.html file. Is it possible to load those libraries after the content of the first html page has been loaded? I am using Angular 2/4?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make your scripts be loaded after additional resources, making them be loaded after things like resources and content, by putting the script tag at the end of your body tag.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653081/why-scripts-at-the-end-of-body-tag) a related question on Stackoverflow for further reference.

Comment: In angular the page content is loaded different from a custom made webpage. <app-root>Loading...</app-root> is being replaced by html content. Do you think this will still work?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Angular CLI you can include `.js` files from your `node_modules` in your `.angular-cli.json` so when the CLI bundles your application all your JS libraries are included as well.

Right under the the `styles` array and above the `environmentSource` you should see the `scripts` array. I've included a little bit (I've truncated it) of the JSON as reference for you.

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```