# Why delete function is not calling on clicking span tag appended in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am clicking value that is appended in div but delete function is not 
    calling Can anyone tell me where i am doing wrong

```
 $("#dropDown").change(function () {
        var value = $('#dropDown').val();
        $("#div").append('<span onclick="deleteValue()">'+value+'</span>');
     })

   function deleteValue()
    {
        alert("Delete function called.");
    }
```

This is my HTML

```
<select id = "dropDown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: Have you defined `deleteValue` function in global scope? Better use Event delegation for dynamic elements

Comment: Is `deleteValue` declared at the root level? In any case you should stop using inline event handlers. Just use `$("<span>").text(value).click(deleteValue).appendTo("#div")`

Comment: Can you show your HTML? Because you are appending your value to `div whose id is div` like this `<div id="div">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the `script` at the bottom of `body` as per the following code snippet to make the `deleteValue()` to work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <select id="dropDown">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <div id="div">
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#dropDown").change(function() {
      var value = $('#dropDown').val();
      $("#div").append('<span onclick="deleteValue()">' + value + '</span>');
    });

    function deleteValue() {
      alert("Delete function called.");
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you John R It's working, Can u explain how it is different writing script after the body?

Comment: @karun For JavaScript events you need define the JavaScript functions either in the head section or at the bottom of body section. To enable both the jQuery events and JavaScript events, you need to define at the bottom of body. [Additional Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653081/why-scripts-at-the-end-of-body-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trigger` for this and use `html` instead of `append` to prevent fire element multi pal times.

```js
$("#dropDown").off().on('change', function(e) {
  var value = $('#dropDown').val();
  $("#div").html('<span onclick="deleteValue()">' + value + '</span>');
  $('#div').find('span').trigger('click');
});
function deleteValue() {
  console.log("Delete function called.");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<div id="div">
</div>
```