# Webpage eventlistener and script section not running

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to make a basic webpage where you can type a message for it to be displayed on the website. However, the script section of my website does not seem to work.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
      {

          let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
          submit.addEventListener('click',function()
          {

                let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
                let input = document.querySelector('input');
                for (let i =0; i< questions.length; i++)
                {
                  if questions[i].innerHTML == ""
                  {
                    questions[i].innerHTML = 'a';
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      continue;
                  }
                }
          });
        function myfunction()
          {
            alert('test');
          }
      });


  </script>
    <title>Write A Message!</title>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
    <h1>How to write a message</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Type a Message into the textbox below to display a public letter!</p>

    <div>
      <input type = 'text'>
      <button id = 'submit'>Type a message!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Message 1!</h1>
      <hr>
      <p class = 'question'></p>
      <h2>Message 2!</h2>
      <hr>
      <p class = 'question'></p>
      <h3>Message 3!</h3>
      <hr>
      <p class = 'question'></p>
      <button onclick = 'myfunction()'>test</button>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

I tried adding a button that would display an alert as well but it does not run as well when clicked.

Comment: add your script as the last item in `body` tag, not within `head` tag.

Comment: Refer to this [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65454504/9499523) on why it your alert is not working

Comment: I've moved it to the bottom of body but it still does not work, for my code above I have the DOMContentLoaded eventlistener shown in the explanation but it does not seem to work as well

Answer (score 0):

First, javscript that contains listener/reference to DOM elements is better to include in the end on body, avoid putting in head.

Second, `myfunction()` is not accessible bebcause you included it under `DOMContentLoaded`. It should be outside of the listener (global scope).

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Write A Message!</title>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
    <h1>How to write a message</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Type a Message into the textbox below to display a public letter!</p>

    <div>
      <input type='text'>
      <button id='submit'>Type a message!</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1>Message 1!</h1>
      <hr>
      <p class='question'></p>
      <h2>Message 2!</h2>
      <hr>
      <p class='question'></p>
      <h3>Message 3!</h3>
      <hr>
      <p class='question'></p>
      <button onclick='myfunction()'>test</button>
    </div>
<script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    let submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click',function(){
        let questions = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
        let input = document.querySelector('input');
        for (let i =0; i< questions.length; i++){
            if (questions[i].innerHTML == ""){
                questions[i].innerHTML = 'a';
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    });
});
    function myfunction() {
        alert('test');
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, avoid the use of inline on* handlers.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification. By not using inline do you mean the open bracket to be put on the same line as declaring the handler?

Comment: It means that avoiding calling function inline within html like `onclick="myfunction()"`. Instead set an unique id/class to the element and then attach onclick listener in javascript to trigger the function.